# Custom function to loop through a 2D array used as a calendar - Google App Script

Tags: function, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a custom function that finds the last activity performed and returns the next activity in thesequence. [Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit#gid=0), e.g. "Chess" is followed in by "Pilates" and then "Elevate". Then next activity is "Kundalini", etc. Once, the last activity is done, the cycle repeats.

Essentially, loop through a 2D array that's a calendar, find the last (most recent) activity and then return the next value from the alt_activity range. If the previous activity is the last value from the alt_activity range, start from the start of the alt_activity range once more.

```
/**
* Looks for the alternate workout in the LAST matching value within the calendar.
* @param {array} input The calendar array to be searched.
* @return The first match starting from the last row (WEEK) and column (DAY) of the @param.
* @customfunction
*/
function calender_search(calendar_range, alt_activities_range)
{
//Search by ROW(), COLUMN() think of ADDRESS function in spreadsheets
//rows are weeks within the calendar
//let week = Object.keys(calendar_range);

for (week = calendar_range.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
for (day = calendar_range[week].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
// look for the match from the alt_activities_range. IF -1 returned (no match) continue loop
IF (alt_activities_range.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) > -1)
{
IF (calendar_range[week][day].indexOf(alt_activities_range) = alt_activties_range.length - 1)
{
return alt_activities_range[0];
}
//Go to index of match PLUS 1 for NEXT value to be returned
return calendar_range[week][day].indexOf(alt_activities_range) + 1;
}

}
}
}
```

Table 1

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wrkout Alternatives | Chess | Pilates | Elevate | Kundalini | Scrabble | Gardening | Darning |

| Column I |
| --- |
| Crossword |

Table 2

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | DAY 1 | DAY 2 | DAY 3 | DAY 4 | DAY 5 | DAY 6 |
| WEEK 1 |  |  |  |  |  | Chess |
| WEEK 2 |  |  |  |  | Pilates | Elevate |
| WEEK 3 |  |  |  | Kundalini | Scrabble | Gardening |
| WEEK 4 |  |  | Darning | Crossword | Chess | Pilates |

Created the custom function but the results are not what I was expecting from what I've been able to piece together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulo operator % is used to wrap around to the beginning of alt_activities_range when the last activity is reached.

```
function calender_search(calendar_range, alt_activities_range) {
  for (let week = calendar_range.length - 1; week >= 0; week--) {
    for (let day = calendar_range[week].length - 1; day >= 0; day--) {
      if (alt_activities_range.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) > -1) {
        if (calendar_range[week][day] === alt_activities_range[alt_activities_range.length - 1]) {
          return alt_activities_range[0];
        }
        // Go to index of match PLUS 1 for NEXT value to be returned
        return alt_activities_range[(alt_activities_range.indexOf(calendar_range[week][day]) + 1) % alt_activities_range.length];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Had me tied in knots and pulling out my non-existant hair trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Drew254 You welcome! Happy to see that helps you :)